# PHP file cache triggers a Internal 307 == insecure warning

Tags: php, google-chrome

In a PHP 7.1 app I load files from a php file "filecache.php" - it works fine in regards of returning a cachable file.

But the thing that drives me crazy is that the images triggers a Insecure content warning in Chrome and FF (perhaps others also).

The files are loaded using a  tag, I tried relative url  and this gives me the error. I've also tried using complete url https://example.com/filecache?f=0983490842'> same error.

The server uses HSTS and LetsEncrypt cert - no http traffic allowed.

When I examine the Network activity in Chrome (and FF) I can see that the browser tries to retrieve a file using https, finds it in the cache which gives a 307 internal redirect - but to a http url - finally ending up with the image loaded over https from the cache. Well at least thats how I read the info below.

[image]

Any input or pointers will be greatly appreciated!

**filecache.php**

```
if(file_exists($file)){
  if(substr($_GET["f"],-3)=="jpg") Header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
  if(substr($_GET["f"],-3)=="png") header("Content-Type: image/png");
  header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*365));
  header('Expires: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+365 days")));
  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate(DATE_RFC1123,filemtime($file)));
  readfile($file);
}else{
  die("no such file");
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add more information on this topic, by adding my .htaccess file.


`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; preload; includeSubDomains" env=HTTPS`